# О правильности оформления цитаты с личным местоимением

Tags: цитирование, местоимение

*Уэллсу не верилось, «**что такая прелесть, какой мне казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете**»* (Б. Акунин,  2022 г.)

Я полагаю, что цитата **оформлена неверно,** так как в одном предложении  встречается 1-е и 3-е лицо, отнесенные к одному персонажу (Уэллс, мне).

Если это так, то какое оформление следует считать верным с учетом того, что цитирование должно быть **дословным**.

Comment: Это ведь не единственный пример такого цитирования. В этом же абзаце, в конце: *Однако Герберт был уже на седьмом десятке и считал, что не имеет права связывать женщину, которой «будет лучше, если ей придется найти себе место в жизни, независимое от меня».*

Comment: Спасибо, но это ведь тоже неправильное оформление?

Comment: Но ведь кавычки стоят из-за местоимения. Если уж цитируем, то нельзя менять. Но "что" никак нельзя в цитату.

Comment: @oleedd "что" действительно есть в оригинальном тексте Уэллса. Проблема в следующем: автор решил, будто "что" из цитаты способно сыграть одновременно роль того "что", которым должно присоединяться придаточное.

Comment: @Nektoid "Что" не может быть в оригинальном тексте Уэллса, потому что это не русский писатель. "Что" здесь присоединяет придаточное, его нельзя включать в цитату, даже если оно есть в оригинальном тексте. А если необходимо процитировать, надо так: *что "что...*

Comment: @oleedd я имел в виду, конечно, перевод.

Comment: @Nektoid Это понял, просто "оригинальный текст Уэллса", на мой взгляд, применимо только к материалу самого писателя, а он на английском. Сказал бы "исходный" или "цитируемый".

Comment: Здесь это считается стилистической ошибкой: https://www.kadrof.ru/mk/20894 (пункт 4).

Answer (score 1):

Цитирование должно быть дословным, но не без купюр или авторских слов.

> Уэллсу не верилось, «что такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась Мура,
> может и вправду существовать на свете».

> Уэллсу не верилось, «что такая прелесть, какой <*ему — Б.А.*> казалась Мура,
> может и вправду существовать на свете».

Comment: Второй вариант, кажется, неверен: разве пометка автора отменяет необходимость отмечать многоточием выпущенное слово?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Мне нравится первый вариант.  А можно "что" убрать за кавычки?  Уэллсу не верилось, что "такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете».

Comment: @Sharon, oleedd утверждает (обосновывая ненужность многоточия в начале цитаты), — она синтаксически связанна с авторским текстом. Добавлю: крепко в него вписана. И на слух, и визуально перемещение кавычек ничего не изменит. Если и есть повод, то только для исключения из цитаты проблемного **мне**: "Уэллсу не верилось, что такая «прелесть», какой ему «казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете»".

Comment: Но "что" нельзя в цитату, потому что оно здесь присоединяет придаточное, цитируемый союз не может грамматически ничего присоединять, а если хотите, надо использовать два "что".

Answer (score 1):

Убрать "что" за кавычки — и цитата станет выглядеть корректнее: *Уэллсу не верилось, что «...такая прелесть, какой мне казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете»*.

Можно было также использовать косвенную речь, чтобы избежать конфликта лиц: *Уэллсу не верилось, что такая прелесть, какой ему казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне неясно, каким должно быть правильное оформление  цитирования в ЭТОЙ КНИГЕ,  то есть в чем ТАМ ошибка.  Мешает местоимение 1-го лица. Могу я использовать купюру и оформить, как предлагает shampar?  Его вариант: Уэллсу не верилось, «что такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете».  У меня нет задачи что-либо редактировать, это только проверка.  Изменять тексту внутри цитаты, как я понимаю, нельзя, а купирование возможно.

Comment: @Sharon "что", которое я предлагаю поставить перед кавычками, и "что", которое предлагаю удалить из цитаты — это два разных "что". То есть сие не изменение текста внутри цитаты, а удаление одного слова с отметкой этого удаления многоточием: тоже купюра, но в другом месте. А "что" перед цитатой необходимо по правилам оформления цитат, когда цитата даётся как придаточное.

Comment: Приведите ваш книжный вариант в корректном виде. Или его можно вообще не исправлять? Меня только это интересует, есть там ошибка или нет.  Если правила это допускают, то ничего не поделаешь — таковы правила.

Comment: @Sharon **1)** "Уэллсу не верилось, что «...такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете»" **2)** "Уэллсу не верилось, что такая прелесть, какой ему казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете".

Comment: @Sharon ошибка там, на мой взгляд, именно в том, что нет нормального ввода в придаточное. Тем не менее есть ещё стилистическая ошибка, то есть ломающее мозг построение наподобие «Иван был уверен, что "я так больше не могу"». Поэтому мой ответ: в таких случаях следует использовать косвенную цитату: «Иван был уверен, что он так больше не может». Купюра тоже возможна, но мне это кажется более громоздким решением — и она НЕ ОТМЕНЯЕТ необходимости нормально оформить ввод в придаточное: не за счёт куска цитаты, а за счёт отдельного "что".

Comment: Спасибо, теперь ясно. Если они выбрали цитирование, то купюра обязательна. Если я использую свое "что", то нужно многоточие. Это верно? Значит, в любом слуае ошибка у них есть?

Comment: @Sharon на мой взгляд — так. Если быть совсем въедливым, то уточнение, упущенное при купюре, следует возместить: "Уэллсу не верилось, что «...такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась *(ему — Б. А.)* Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете»". Но это совсем уж "научное цитирование". А в публицистике выглядит так, будто автор открещивается: мол, это ему Мура казалась прелестью, а не мне :)

Comment: Спасибо вам за внимание к моему вопросу. Ну и как вам издательская группа "Альпина"? Несогласование местоимений я им точно простить не могу.  Надо будет поинтересоваться у знакомых, что они думают на эту тему. Кстати, Акунин в разных местах издавался. Интересно, что у него одновременно вышло подарочное издание этой книги с автографом и блокнотиком.  Вот не знаю, у них или в другом издательстве. И  остались ли там эти ошибки.

Comment: @Sharon по одной книге я бы не судил, тем более что она издана "в авторской редакции". Хоть корректура не редактура, кто знает — может, Акунин сам настоял на всех этих косяках.

Comment: Косяки разные бывают. Есть авторская вариантная пунктуация (вполне обоснованная), ее редактор должен согласовывать с автором.  А есть оформительские ошибки, до которых ему вряд ли есть дело.

Comment: @Nektoid Розенталь: Если цитата приводится не полностью, то пропуск текста обозначается многоточием, которое ставится: 1) перед цитатой (после открывающих кавычек), **синтаксически не связанной с авторским текстом**, для указания, что цитата приводится не с начала предложения. У нас здесь синтаксически связано, многоточие не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**Как я понимаю «встроенное» цитирование**

Из цитаты автор берет часть текста и встраивает его  в свое предложение. Если убрать кавычки, то никто и не догадается, что это цитата: *Уэллсу не верилось, что такая прелесть, какой казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете.* Здесь все слова синтаксически связаны между собой.

Но автору важно показать, что здесь есть дословное высказывание какого-то лица, и **эту часть текста** он заключает в кавычки. В нашем случае  такому оформлению мешало **местоимение**, но его можно изъять и обозначить как купюру.

У нас получается следующее предложение: ***Уэллсу не верилось, что «такая прелесть, какой <...> казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете».***

Это правильное оформление? Есть ли ошибки в моих рассуждениях и действиях?

Comment: Строго говоря, купюра в одно слово (а не в целое предложение) отмечается просто многоточием, а не многоточием в угловых скобках, если мне не изменяет память. Я сперва этого не приметил, а теперь обратил внимание. // Мне понравилась идея Shampar: "Уэллсу не верилось, что такая «прелесть», какой ему «казалась Мура, может и вправду существовать на свете»". (Поскольку в комментарии нельзя абзацировать текст, я решил использовать в качестве знака абзаца два слэша.)

Comment: А мне кажется допустимым использование цитаты с местоимением, хоть и не очень удачным. Прежде всего в примере, который привела Римма, а здесь как-то не очень, потому что не однозначно понятно, кто имеется в виду под местоимением "мне". Но сама по себе идея не очень удачна, потому что здесь гибрид косвенной речи и цитаты и и то и то относится к одному лицу. Вот если в косвенной речи цитировать кого-то/что-то другое, тогда порядок.

Comment: Как обозначаются купюры (многоточием, угловыми скобками)? Где найти это правило, которое вы упоминаете?

Comment: @Sharon Мильчин "Справочник издателя и автора". Конкретно о угловых скобках — п. 8.5.4, но вообще весь раздел интересно прочитать, там весьма подробно изложены современные правила цитирования: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html

Comment: @Sharon пожалуйста, упоминайте меня через @ при обращении, иначе оповещения не приходят. Я бы пропустил ваш вопрос, если бы не залез в тему поглядеть, чё тут да как :)

Comment: @Nektoid
 Большое спасибо, посмотрю.